# Add Dark and Highlight effect on image Like apple native app Dark and Highlight effect

Tags: swift, core-image

Hi Every one I am facing issue regarding to implement Dark and Highlight effect using Core Image builtin filters. I have worked with other filters but this one giving me wrong result or may be I am not using right filter. I am using CIFilter.highlightShadowAdjust filter Here is my implementation.

```
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let filter = CIFilter.highlightShadowAdjust()
    let aCIImage = CIImage(image: self.image)
    filter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    filter.setValue(highlitValue, forKey: "inputHighlightAmount")
    filter.setValue(shadowValue, forKey: "inputShadowAmount")
    filter.setValue(radiousValue, forKey: "inputRadius")
    
    guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else {return UIImage()}
    guard let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else {return UIImage()}
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
```

For clarification I also uploaded a [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11hZy8JacRXEll9g0qN2xRjZrWh4EpCzt/view?usp=sharing) what I want to achieve.

Any Suggestion or guid will be greatly thankful.